# The set of irreducible polynomials of order at most $ d $ contains a non-empty open subset

Tags: general-topology, combinatorics, algebraic-geometry

I'mtrying to solve the following problem:

Suppose $ d \in \mathbb{N} $ and let $ K[x_1, \dots, x_n]_d $ denote the affine space of all polynomials of $ n $ variables of order at most $ d $ over an algebraically closed field $ K $. The aim is to prove that the set of all irreducible polynomials contains a non-empty open subset.

I believe that the dimension of our space is ${n + d \choose d} $ (by a simple stars-and-bars argument) and it might be crucial for further reasoning - but I don't really know how to go on from this spot.

I would appreciate any hints

Comment: If $d_1+d_2=d$, can you say $\binom{n+d_1}{d_1}+\binom{n+d_2}{d_2}<\binom{n+d}{d}$ or something similar? Notice that a polynomial of degree $d$ is not irreducible  means there exists polynomials of some degrees $d_1,d_2$ with $d_1+d_2=d$ and their product is the given polynomial.